# How to call another autogenerated action within an autogenerated action of redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm developing a small game. And so i used the redux-toolkit for the first time. (i'm used to redux)

this `createSlice` method is awesome but i cannot figure out how to call actions inside actions.
so the actions are autogenerated and therefore not available before generation.

example:

```
const gameSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'game',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        startNewGame: (state) => {
            state.activeTeam = state.config.startTeam = random(0, 1)
            state.winner = undefined
        },
        endRound: (state, action, dispatch) => { // last param not available
            // ... code that handles the rounds inputs and counts points for each team ...
            if(state.red >= 30) {
                // HOW?! Here's something i tried
                endGame(state, Team.Red)
                dispatch({type: endGame, payload: Team.Red})
                dispatch({type: gameSlice.endGame, payload: Team.Red})
            }
            if(state.blue >= 30) {
                // HOW?! Here's something i tried
                endGame(state, Team.Blue)
                dispatch({type: endGame, payload: Team.Blue})
                dispatch({type: gameSlice.endGame, payload: Team.Blue})
            }
        },
        endGame: (state, action) => {
            state.winner = action.payload
        }
    }
})
```

This is just a small example. There is nothing `async` and no backend-call. I just want to nest action-calls. Simple as hell is suppose... but i have no idea how to do it in a KISS-way.

I read something with `extraReducers` and `createAsyncThunk` but i won't do this for every action as i have no async stuff in here and because then there is no benefit in using redux-toolkit anymore. It's just a hell of more code for nothing.

I think i'm blind or stupid or just confused... but this drives me crazy, right now.

Without redux-toolkit this was easy.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if i declare my functions outside the `createSlice` like: `const _endGame = (state: Draft<GameState>) => { //...code }` then i can call them from each other. This is easy but feels and looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can *never* dispatch more actions inside of a Redux reducer, ever.**

However, you *can* write additional helper functions to do common update tasks in reducers, and call those functions as needed.  This can be especially helpful when using Immer-powered reducers in RTK's `createSlice`.

Additionally, you *can* call other case reducers as needed, by referring to the `slice.caseReducers` object like:

```js
reducers: {
  endRound(state, action) {
    if (someCondition) {
      // "Mutate" state using the `endGame` case reducer
      mySlice.caseReducers.endGame(state)
    }

  },
  endGame(state, action) {}
}
```